# How to pass a vector of vectors from class to function without copying?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I wrote this program where I need to transfer a `vector<vector<int>>` from a class to a function to change every `0` in the vector to a `1`. This function works, but somewhere a copy of vector is created and the elements are only changed to `0` in the copy, not in the original vector. How can I fix this problem?

```
class Matrix {
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &in, IntArr& a) {...}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Matrix& a) {...}
  private:
    vector < vector <int> > v;
    int rows, cols;
  public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
        v.resize(rows, vector<int>(cols));
    }
    // ...
    vector < vector <int> > GetPointer() {
        return v;
    }
    int GetRows() {
        return rows;
    }
    int GetCols() {
        return cols;
    }
};

void IndividualTask(int rows, int cols, vector < vector <int> > v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (v[i][j] == 0) {
                v[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Matrix arr1(2, 2);
    cin >> arr1;
    IndividualTask(arr1.GetRows(), arr1.GetCols(), arr1.GetPointer());
    cout << arr1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're obviously passing the vector by value, rather than by reference. That's where the copy is made. You fix the problem by passing the vector parameter by reference, rather than value.

Comment: I try to do this. 
void IndividualTask(int rows, int cols, vector < vector <int> >& v) {...} - Didn't help

Comment: You're `InvidiualTask` function is broken. You have all the information you need to determine the size of each element of v, but decide to use a userdefined value -- that's error prone and just plain bad design. Use ranged-based for loops instead. Also, do what @SamVarshavchik says, and make `v` a reference.

Comment: `GetPointer`, returns a copy of `v`, not a reference (or even a pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of related problems you absolutely need to solve first. `GetPointer` returns a copy, and `IndividualTask` takes a copy. You'll want both of these to work by adding `&` to the type to make them references

First, have `GetPointer` return a reference.

```
//        right here---+
//                     |
//                     v
vector < vector <int> >& GetPointer() {
    return v;
}
```

Second, have `IndividualTask` take a reference

```
//                                         and again here------+
//                                                             |
//                                                             v 
void IndividualTask(int rows, int cols, vector < vector <int> >& v) {
   // ...
}
```

---

There is a separate problem here, with the `rows` and `cols`. A `std::vector` already knows its size, this isn't C, you don't need to pass around array sizes like this.

You could rewrite `GetRows` and `GetCols` (which should be const anyway) to delegate to the vector's size, and not have the `Matrix` store `rows` and `cols` data members

```
int GetRows() const {
    return v.size();
}
int GetCols() const {
    // guard against the empty vector case
    if (v.empty()) { return 0; }
    // only correct if all rows have the same number of columns
    return return v[0].size();
}
```

This is more than just convenience, it's correct. If someone were to change the size of your `v` by doing `m.GetPointer().resize(N);` your current `GetRows` and `GetCols` would be wrong!

Your function could also use these qualities of the vector,

```
void IndividualTask(vector < vector <int> >& v) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++) {
            if (v[i][j] == 0) {
                v[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using `C++11` or alter, you can use a ranged for loop more easily

```
void IndividualTask(vector < vector <int> >& v) {
    for (auto& row : v) {
        for (auto& e : row) {
            if (e == 0) {
                e = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You answer is very helpful for me!

Comment: A `vector<int>` with simulated 2D indexes would be much better anyway. Like, _much_.